# Create field from file name condition in logstash

Tags: conditional-statements, logstash, translate, elk

I have several logs with the following names, where [E-1].[P-28], [E-1].[P-45] and [E-1].[P-51] are operators that generate these logs (They do not appear within the data. I can only identify them by obtaining from the file name)

p2sajava131.srv.gva.es_11101.log.online.[E-1].[P-28].21.01.21.log

p1sajava130.srv.gva.es_11101.log.online.[E-1].[P-45].21.03.04.log

p1sajava130.srv.gva.es_11101.log.online.[E-1].[P-51].21.03.04.log

...

is it posible to use translate filter create a new field?
somethink like:

```
translate{
field => "[log.file.path]"
         destination => "[operator_name]"
         dictionary => {
            if contains "[E-1].[P-28]" => "OPERATOR-1"
            if contains "[E-1].[P-45]" => "OPERATOR-2"
            if contains "[E-1].[P-51]" => "OPERATOR-3"
```

thanx

Answer (score 0):

I don't have ELK here so I can't test but this should works

```
if [log][file][path] =~ "[E-1].[P-28]" {
    mutate {
        add_field => { "[operator][name]" => "OPERATOR-1" }
    }
}

if [log][file][path] =~ "[E-1].[P-45]" {
    mutate {
        add_field => { "[operator][name]" => "OPERATOR-2" }
    }
}

if [log][file][path] =~ "[E-1].[P-51]" {
    mutate {
        add_field => { "[operator][name]" => "OPERATOR-3" }
    }
}
```